# Where to enter URL for Live Preview in Craft 3?

Tags: live-preview

Pretty sure I've seen where you can enter the URL for an entry type so Craft knows what page to display during live preview. But I can't find that now. I'm looking in the entry types, and I can't think of anywhere else it would be.

Am I going crazy? Where is that feature?

I see a field in the section settings called "Preview Targets". It says:

> Additional locations that should be available for previewing entries
>   in this section.

If this is it, the term "Additional" is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Entry URI Format" in Section settings is used for Live Preview by default. If you add additional "Preview Targets," then the Entry URI Format will show up as "Primary entry page" in the list of Live Preview options.

Preview Targets are "additional" because they aren't required and not used for template routing, unlike the "Entry URI Format" above it. They're only used for Live Preview mode.

[The Craft docs on Preview Targets](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sections-and-entries.html#preview-targets) use the example of a blog post that you want to preview how it will look as an excerpt on the homepage or in a listing page like the blog index in addition to its main entry page.